# Firefox addon to display bytes downloaded per tab

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

Is there a Firefox add-on that can display number of bytes downloaded for each tab?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)? It has way more features than just bytes downloaded, as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you mean the "Net" tab of Firebug? Although I have Firebug installed for ages, I didn't know it was there until I read your answer :) That's a very cool feature. But it takes too much screen space. It would be great if the info could be displayed in the status bar. (I tried to upvote your answer but upvote requires 15 reputation, I have only one :(

Comment: Yes, the net tab. Unfortunately, it's a lot of screen real estate.